# Connect to Python and Mysql from Android

Tags: php, android, python, mysql

I am writing an assistant like Siri in Android. The app will perform natural language processing, for which I need NLTK in Python and I already developed python code for it. Now, based on the NLP processing, I also need to search in MySQL database and then send the result back to my android app.

So, what will happen is as follow:
User provides a query in android app, it needs to be transmitted to Python for NLP processing and after that I have to develop some SQL queries for searching in MYSQL, I have to send back the result in Android again.

Here, one big problem is to identify, how I will send data from Android to Python. I found the web framework of Python which is Flask and using it I can pass data through url to python. In this way, I can call the URL from android app and pass the query to the URL, which will be received by flask. This is my plan to build the connection with python. But so far Flask only give me one single ip. Is it possible to assign a domain to it so that my app can work from anywhere?

Secondly, How will send data back from Flask to android? Is there any better way for it? Should I send the SQL queries which I generate in python back to android and then process it again from there? Because connecting to MYSQL is much easier with android>php script>mysql than python>mysql, as it seems now. For python 3.5, which I am using, I am not finding any good framework which will allow me remote access to MySQL. (I tried PyMysql, Python MySQL connector has no support for python 3)

It would be great if anyone have any better idea. This implementation seems very complex to me.

Comment: Sounds like you need a REST API. You can implement that with Flask easily.  Check out Flask-RESTul http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/

Comment: Sounds interesting. However I am wondering how I can implement it. Flask only allow access with an url.

Comment: There is a list of DBAPIs available. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html. You might want to check SQLAlchemy for connection to mySQL

Comment: I am going to check this!